# Brakepoints in xcode subproject don't work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, static, subproject

We have static lib project, and other "sample" project.
I added static lib project as a subproject to "sample" project and also to target dependancy.
When I run "sample" brakepoints work properly, but not in subproject (static lib).
Is it possible somehow to debug my subproject, or it's impossible if it's static lib?

**UPDATED**
Fixed:

[image]

For some reasons "Generate Debugging symbols" flag was set to NO

Answer (score 0):

Create one workspace and put it as separate projects. Now You need to add static lib in sample project. So add library from sub project product folder (where your lib get created) as reference. It will work also for debugging and whenever you will build for static lib that changes will reflect in sample project also.